# Decrypt encrypted key using Certificate not working in .NET but works in SOAP UI

Tags: c#, encryption, soap, cryptography

I'm trying to figure out why I can't seem to decrypt an encrypted key from .NET with a X509 Certificate.

```
    encryptedKey = "jW3VDsUZWIdzfZ1bPN3iKI2Pf9u22kUax0DFnF3A9H+nvcBQuVC2efw1FYGm5/AvnN27kXqA4PyCqcQLp/tguVqHtzdR7mJtkTCyY8TUoAej2Mqzv2uiEKULB/8rlPDl2DOkSMGJqieenAG/7gZjWhlU0eYrlcMi5dtAnPFTfy+LvtJ6bbGEDgy4FhoT49T6sO0kjBJHp5YI0p/CeEuc+WMT/BMGG1YuDPswltj0VzeaE3KbHSLvJPjGCQ3U0YkUWm8h9zM22S/mRvfMhEu1aRdQpojGUiSLKUJyotNu8fRulKeB1TVuE7AlDGrbAUsRtU+y6PdLMcEHW+BRq5Uouw==";

    var encryptedKeyByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedKey);

    var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certificates\xxxxx.pfx", "xxxx");
    var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)clientCert.PrivateKey;
    byte[] key = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedKeyByte, false);
```

The error I get when I try to run the last line of the code `rsa.Decrypt(encryptedKeyByte, false)`

> The parameter is incorrect.

In SOAP UI the decryption works where I use the same certificate.  I just had to convert the file pfx to a jks file to get it working in SOAP UI.  But other than that the settings look the same to me. 
Here is a screen shot of the SOAP UI settings.  I'm guessing the Signature Keystore in the SOAP UI seetings is not used for the decryption process.  The Decrypt Keystore settings in SOAP UI is the one I'm using in .NET.  Only in .NET its a pfx file.

[image]

Here is the certificate details from MMC
[image]

[image]

[image]

Stacktrace Error:

Server stack trace:

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 503
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 458
   at Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments.SwaEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType) in C:\Crap\Stuff\CARES\Microsoft.Austria.WcfHelpers.SoapWithAttachments\SwaEncoder.cs:line 126
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
```

Comment: I am assuming that the encryptedKey is the value you want to decrypt?

Comment: Yes.  As a step 1.  Then use that to decrypt the body.  Currently I can't even get passed step one.

Comment: What's the Type of the raised exception please?

Comment: @NeilMoss I get the error "The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: But what Type? e.g. CryptpgraphicException, ArgumentOutOfRangeException, InvalidOperationException ?

Comment: @NeilMoss I added the stack trace error above.

Comment: Last check then - can you query the property clientCert.HasPrivateKey and report whether it is true or false. 
If true, all I can think of then is that the encryptedKey value is the result of encryption using a different certificate. If false, the certificate doesn't contain a private key with which to be able to try a decryption.

Comment: I checked that.  It has a private key.  It works in SOAP UI with a jks file that was created with pfx file.

Comment: I don't have any other certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Might this class will help you:

```
public class TFRSAEncryption
{
    public string RsaEncryptWithPublic(string clearText, string publicKey)
    {
        var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

        var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
        {
            var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
        }

        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));
        return encrypted;

    }

    public string RsaEncryptWithPrivate(string clearText, string privateKey)
    {
        var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

        var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(privateKey))
        {
            var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            encryptEngine.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
        }

        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));
        return encrypted;
    }


    // Decryption: 

    public string RsaDecryptWithPrivate(string base64Input, string privateKey)
    {
        var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
        var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(privateKey))
        {
            keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
        }

        var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
        return decrypted;
    }

    public string RsaDecryptWithPublic(string base64Input, string publicKey)
    {
        var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);

        var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
        {
            var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            decryptEngine.Init(false, keyParameter);
        }

        var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, 0, bytesToDecrypt.Length));
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error leads me to believe that the encrypted data is not able to be decrypted using the method specified. You might try this way where you specifically use .GetRSAPrivateKey() and then decrypt using the correct padding method.

To my knowledge there is no way to know what padding method is being used but you could iterate through the options and see if one works for you.

```
var certPath = @"c:\code\temp\xxxxxxxxx.pfx";
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "xxxxxxx");
var decryptedData = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey().Decrypt(encryptedByteInfo, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
```

This article list the padding methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where are you getting GetRSAPrivateKey?  That method does not exists.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: VS 2015.  Not using .NET Core.  You must be using that.  You have the solution in 2015?

Comment: Thanks.  Why do you think its padding issue?

Comment: The error indicates that the encrypted data is not in the expected format. When I played with my own implementation in .NET 4.6 the padding was one simple way I could "break" things that would make it work in one instance and not another.

Comment: I see.  I don't see settings to change the padding anywhere.

Comment: The padding is set when the value is encrypted. I might be barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169702/discussion-between-aaron-havens-and-mindgame).